# Extract multiple instances of text between the same two lines of text

Tags: text-processing, sed

My file is in JSON format is looks like this:

```
name: Tom species: mouse name: Stu species: cat name: Carter species: Dog
```

I have a file that is one long string, and I would like to extract only the names from this list.  So the desired output is something like this:

```
Tom Stu Carter
```

I've had a lot of failed attempts at sed, for example

```
cat alphabet | sed 's/^.*name: \(.*\) species*/\1/g'
```

Output:

```
Tom species: mouse name: Stu species: cat name: Carter : Dog
```

I have a lot of really big files I'd like to do this with so if there is an efficient way to go about this that would be great

Comment: Your sample text is not in JSON format.

Answer (score 1):

If your input actually was JSON, then a JSON tool should be used.

The format that it is in appears to be suitable for awk:

```
$ awk '{for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) if ($(i-1)=="name:") print $i}' file
Tom
Stu
Carter
```

This looks at every field `i` on a line, starting with the second field.  If the previous field was `name:`, then it prints the current field.

To keep all the output on one line (without a trailing blank):

```
$ awk '{for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) if ($(i-1)=="name:") {printf "%s%s", f,$i; f=" "}; print""}' file
Tom Stu Carter
```

Answer (score 1):

With GNU grep:

```
grep -Po 'name: \K[^ ]*' file | tr '\n' ' '
```

or with GNU sed:

```
sed -r 's/name: ([^ ]*) species: [^ ]*/\1/g' file
```

Output:

```
Tom Stu Carter
```